# Fancy arrows to signify continuation of pmatrix

Tags: equations, tikz-arrows, arrows

I think my request is a bit hard, but I'm trying anyway.
I have this `align` environment

```
\begin{align} \nonumber
    \f = \begin{pmatrix}
    f(x_1, y_1) \\ f(x_2, y_1) \\ \vdots \\ f(x_{N - 1}, y_1) \\ f(x_N, y_1)
    \end{pmatrix}
    &&
    \begin{pmatrix}
    f(x_1, y_2) \\ f(x_2, y_2) \\ \vdots \\ f(x_{N - 1}, y_2) \\ f(x_N, y_2)
    \end{pmatrix}
    &&
    \begin{pmatrix}
    f(x_1, y_N) \\ f(x_2, y_N) \\ \vdots \\ f(x_{N - 1}, y_N) \\ f(x_N, y_N)
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
```

I would like to make arrows between the `pmatrix`'s in this way

[image]

Any idea for an approach?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: with use of `tikzmark` library?

Comment: I'd say `f=\begin{pmatrix} f_1 \\ f_2 \\ \vdots \\ f_N\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{where}\quad f_i=\begin{pmatrix} f(x_1,y_i} \\ f(x_2,y_i} \\ \vdots \\ f(x_N,y_i) \end{pmatrix},\quad i=1,2,\dots,N`

Comment: I would second @egreg's answer. Although other answers have shown you how to achieve the visual effect that you want, it is atypical and therefore difficult to understand. Another notation which is commonly used is: `\DeclareMathOperator{\VEC}{vec}` followed by `f = \VEC(f_1, \dots, f_N)` where `f_i = \VEC(f(x_1, y_i), \dots, f(x_N, y_i))`, which is convenient when you are short on vertical space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just put them in a `tikzpicture` and draw the arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
    f = \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(P.base),>={Latex[bend]}]
    \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt](P){\vphantom{1}};
    \path (P) node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,matrix of math nodes,
        ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=1ex
        ] (M){
    {\begin{pmatrix}
    f(x_1, y_1) \\ f(x_2, y_1) \\ \vdots \\ f(x_{N - 1}, y_1) \\ f(x_N, y_1)
    \end{pmatrix}}
    \& \phantom{\vdots}\&
    {\begin{pmatrix}
    f(x_1, y_2) \\ f(x_2, y_2) \\ \vdots \\ f(x_{N - 1}, y_2) \\ f(x_N, y_2)
    \end{pmatrix}}
    \& \textcolor{blue}{\boldsymbol{\vdots}}\&
    {\begin{pmatrix}
    f(x_1, y_N) \\ f(x_2, y_N) \\ \vdots \\ f(x_{N - 1}, y_N) \\ f(x_N, y_N)
    \end{pmatrix}}
    \\
    };
    \draw[blue,thick,->] (M-1-1.south) to[out=-90,in=-90] (M-1-1.south-|M-1-2)
    -- (M-1-3.north-|M-1-2) to[out=90,in=90] (M-1-3.north);
    \draw[blue,thick,->] (M-1-3.south) to[out=-90,in=-90] (M-1-3.south-|M-1-4)
    -- ([yshift=-1ex]M-1-4.south) (M-1-4.north) -- (M-1-5.north-|M-1-4) to[out=90,in=90] (M-1-5.north);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't use tex enough to use tikz, so this is great. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A solution with `pstricks`: each matrix is defined as a BoxNodes, which are linked through intermediate nodes with the `\ncangles` command.

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, bm}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\[ \bm{f} =
    \psDefBoxNodes{M1}{\begin{pmatrix}
    f(x_1, y_1) \\ f(x_2, y_1) \\ \vdots \\ f(x_{N - 1}, y_1) \\ f(x_N, y_1)
    \end{pmatrix}}
   \enspace \pnode{I}\enspace
    \psDefBoxNodes{M2}{\begin{pmatrix}
    f(x_1, y_2) \\ f(x_2, y_2) \\ \vdots \\ f(x_{N - 1}, y_2) \\ f(x_N, y_2)
    \end{pmatrix}}
     \enspace \Rnode{D}{\textcolor{blue}{\boldsymbol{\vdots}}}\enspace
    \psDefBoxNodes{M3}{\begin{pmatrix}
    f(x_1, y_N) \\ f(x_2, y_N) \\ \vdots \\ f(x_{N - 1}, y_N) \\ f(x_N, y_N)
    \end{pmatrix}}
%%arrows
\psset{linewidth=1pt, linecolor=RoyalBlue, arrowinset=0.12, linearc=0.3}
\ncangles[angleA=-90, armA=0.5cm, angleB=-90]{M1:bC}{I}\ncangles[angleA=90, armA=0.5cm, angleB=90, arrows=<-]{M2:tC}{I}
\ncangles[angleA=-90, armA=0.5cm, angleB=-90, nodesepB=3pt]{M2:bC}{D}\ncangles[angleA=90, armA=0.5cm, angleB=90, arrows=<-, nodesepB=-2pt]{M3:tC}{D}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc 
\[ <your code> \] abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc `.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to avoid the hassle of determining the dimensions of a pspicture, so the arrows come as an overlay on the equation. You just have to add a `\bigskip` and a blank line above, and symmetrically, a bigskip and a blank line below.

Comment: Well, it is a bit disturbing that you just took my code, and tried to convert it to PSTricks. If you would have done that more carefully you would have noted that there is a reason why I put `\phantom{\vdots}`: in your output the space between the fist and second matrix is smaller than the space between second and third matrix. I also know that with PSTricks is it a real hassle to determine the bounding box, which is one of the reasons why I put a Ti*k*Z solution, which has a more reasonable though not precise bounding box.